# ColorInput Yii2

Tags: php, yii, frameworks, yii2

I'm using ColorInput (widget from [krajee](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/colorinput)). I have one table with 2 columns (Color_1 and Color_2) and i'm trying show all colors in one page.

```
foreach($array as $value)
{
   echo $form->field($value, 'Color_1')->widget(ColorInput::classname(), [])->label(false);
}
```

After that, only first color works.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsLfW.png)

Anyone have some idea to solve the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: can you post the resulting `html` code?

Answer (score 2):

I solved problem changing the name of each field:

```
echo $form->field($template, "Color1[{$i}]")->widget(ColorInput::classname(), [
 'showDefaultPalette' => true,
 'pluginOptions' => [
     'showPaletteOnly' => true,
     'showSelectionPalette' => true,
     'allowEmpty' => false,
  ]
])->label(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `yii`, but it looks like `$form->field() ...` does not `return` a field, but configures the field. So you configure the same field 4 times. Did you try to `echo` something more and look at the resulting `html` code?

```
foreach($array as $value)
{
   echo $form->field($value, 'Color_1')->widget(ColorInput::classname(), [])->label(false);
   echo ' separator ';
}
```